# Form themeing show pictures

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I went to [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). I got the example to work. But I don't get it because I can't customize it for my case.

I want to display a picture for each of my facebook friend and pass the adress of the profile picture from facebook to an image tag in front of the checkbox element.

**Update**

part of my action:

```
//the array is on part of my update.
$choice_test = array();
$choice_test[] = array('id' => 1, 'username' => 'test');
$choice_test[] = array('id' => 2, 'username' => 'test2');

->add('friend', 'choice', array(
     'required' => true,
     'expanded' => true,
     'choice_list' => $choice_test, //this is my update
     'choices' => $fb_friends_form,  //$fb_friends_form[1]= 'First Lastane';
     'multiple' => true,
     'constraints' => array(new CheckChoicesFbFriends(array('fb_friends_form' => $fb_friends_form))),
     'mapped' => true
     ))

return $this->render('FrontendChancesBundle::createrequest.html.php', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()));
```

template:

```
<?php $view['form']->setTheme($form, array('FrontendDemoBundle:Form')) ;?>
<?php  echo $view['form']->widget($form['friend'])?>
```

in FrontendDemoBundle/Ressources/views/Form/form_widget_pics.html.php:

```
<input
 type="<?php echo isset($type) ? $view->escape($type) : 'checkbox' ?>"
 <?php if (!empty($value)): ?>value="<?php echo $view->escape($value) ?>"<?php endif ?>
 <?php echo $view['form']->block($form, 'checkbox_widget') ?>
 />
```

How can I pass even a variable, in my case the username (`$fb_username[0] = 'username' of facebook to from_widget_pics.html.php and how can I display it like this with the form bulider in my aciton:

```
<img src="www.facebook.com/+FirstLastname> 
<input type="checkbox"
   id="form_friend_0"
   name="form[friend][]"
   value="1"/> 
<label for="form_friend_0" >First Lastname</label>
<img src="www.facebook.com/+nextfriend>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same exception message when trying to pass an array or collection of custom selected objects to a form using 'choice_list' option.

I solved it this way (simplified example):

Controller code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList;


class UsedCarsController extends Controller {

..... action code:

$usedCars = $carRepository->findAllUsed();

$choiceList = new SimpleChoiceList($usedCars);

$form = $this->createForm(new UsedCarsType($choiceList),null, array('label' => 'Used cars form'));

... now render view, etc.
```

UsedCarsType:

```
class UsedCarsType extends AbstractType
{
    private $choicesList;

public function __construct($choicesList)
{
    $this->choicesList = $choicesList;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('usedCars', 'choice',array('label'=>'Used cars',
                                     'required'=>true,
                                     'choice_list' => $this->choicesList,
                                     'empty_value' => '-- used car --'))
        ;
}
```

Choice_list option must be an instance of SimpleChoiceList class, not an array.

A bit late but hope this helps.

BTW: I am using Symfony 2.3